# how to remove double quote from empty array in codable struct

Tags: swift, codable

I'm making a POST request with URLSession. I need to send the following string in the request body:

> `{"rebajados": false, "text": "pantalon", "municipios": [], "departamentos": []}`

so i define a struct to use codable to send data as request body. the struct is this.

```
struct filter: Codable {
  var text: String?
  var departamentos: [String]?
  var municipios: [String]?
  var rebajados = false
}
```

but what I send is this:

```
{
    "departamentos": [
        ""
    ],
    "municipios": [
        ""
    ],
    "rebajados": false,
        "text": "pantalon"
}
```

The backend returns no result because `[""]` makes it lost.
So what's a posible way to make the array a empty array without the double `""`?

Note: I can't modifiy the backend to accept the array with empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all please name structs with a starting capital letter.

An empty string array is encoded as empty JSON array

```
struct Filter : Codable {
    let text : String
    let departamentos : [String]
    let municipios : [String]
    let rebajados : Bool
}

let filter = Filter(text: "pantalon", departamentos: [], municipios: [], rebajados: false)

do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(filter)
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(string) // {"rebajados":false,"municipios":[],"departamentos":[],"text":"pantalon"}

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: changin to var  every element in the struct since mutabilty is needed because the filter would be in singleton, got hte same result the struct with [""]

Comment: Please try my code in a Playground. The JSON arrays are clearly empty.

Comment: now i saw whats happend since a siglenton for filter the struct initialization take as an emty string array so i have to solve like this ` let userDefault =  UserDefaults.standard
        guard let filter = userDefault.object(forKey: "filter") else {
            FilterManager.shared.setFilter(filtro: Filter(text: "", departamentos: [], municipios: [], rebajados: false))
            return
        }
        FilterManager.shared.setFilter(filtro: filter as! Filter)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  struct filter:Codable {
    var text: String?
    var departamentos: [String] = []
    var municipios: [String] = []
    var rebajados = false
   }
```

Comment: same result, i'll aredy hace tried that but got the same result as previous declaration.